# VueJS 2 Error in callback for watcher

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, formwizard

We're using two components called **VueFormWizard**, **vue-paginate**. when we use vue-paginate in VueFormWizard for sorting our data, we get an error like this:

> [Vue warn]: Error in getter for watcher "currentPage": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'allQuestions' of undefined"

[image: screenshot from our error]

our code:

```
{{getAllQuestions}}
<paginate name="allQuestions" :list="allQuestions" :per="2">
  <div class="" v-for="quest in paginated('allQuestions')">
    <label v-bind:class="{selectedQuestionClass:quest==selectedQuestion}"
           @click="selectQuestion(quest)"
           class="form-control allQuest">{{quest.description}}</label>

  </div>
</paginate>
<paginate-links for="allQuestions"></paginate-links>
```

p.s : **getAllQuestions** is a function for retrive all data from our RESTFul API thats get an array.

Comment: Can you post code for `allQuestions` list? also maybe you should change `name="allQuestions"` and `for="allQuestions"` to something different so it's less confusing.